# HTMLUnit not working with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, web-crawler, htmlunit

According to https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/html-snapshot, with HtmlUnit (2.13) I am trying to create a snapshot for a webpage using AngularJS (1.2.1).

My Java code is:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
webClient.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());

webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setAppletEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setPopupBlockerEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(10000);

webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(true);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(true);
webClient.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(true);

HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(new WebRequest(new URL("..."), HttpMethod.GET));
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5000);
String result = page.asXml();
```

Although `webClient.getPage(...)` does not throws any exception the result string still contains "unevaluated angular expressions" such as

```
<div>
    {{name}}
</div>
```

I am aware of http://htmlunit.10904.n7.nabble.com/htmlunit-to-scrape-angularjs-td29931.html#a30075 but the recomendation given there does not work either.

Of course the same GET-request works without exceptions in all current browsers.

Any ideas/experiences how to get HtmlUnit working with AngularJS?

**Update:**

I created a HTMLUnit [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/bugs/1559/).
For the moment, I switched my implementation to PhantomJS. Maybe this code snippet helps others with a similar problem:

```
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", "phantomjs.exe");
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
caps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", false);

PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get(new URL("..."));
String result = driver.getPageSource();
```

**Update2:**
I stoped rendering my pages manually as the Google crawler renders Angular sites itself now

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem but could not use explicit bootstrapping because angular e2e tests don't work with explicit bootstrap.

I solved the problem by using

```
<html id="ng-app" class="ng-app: appmodule;">
```

instead of

```
<html ng-app="appmodule">
```

htmlunit tests work and e2e tests work as well.

Very likely, htmlunit doesn't (fully?) support document.querySelectorAll(). This method is used by angularInit() to find ng-app directives.

The syntactic variant for the ng-app directive works around the document.querySelectorAll() calls in angularInit().

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it solved the problem where HTMLUnit was not resolving the angular directives. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to help, due to HtmlUnit's poor support for AngularJS, but it doesn't resolve all of the issues. Hopefully 2.15 will be better...

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with "unevaluated angular expressions" if I use HtmlUnit. The solution is to [bootstrap application manually](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/docs/guide/bootstrap#overview_manual-initialization). Reproduction steps:

Minimal example of app working in browser, but not with HtmlUnit:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label>Name:</label> <input type="text" ng-model="yourName"
            placeholder="Enter a name here">
        <hr>
        <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Modification steps:

1. [Bootstrap manually](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/docs/guide/bootstrap#overview_manual-initialization)
2. [Remove ng-app to not bootstrap app twice](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/docs/guide/bootstrap#comment-971499790)
3. [If you use $http or like you should re-sync it with](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#AJAXDoesNotWork):

   webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());

And now working example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.element(document).ready(function() {
            angular.module('myApp', []);
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label>Name:</label> <input type="text" ng-model="yourName"
            placeholder="Enter a name here">
        <hr>
        <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Test:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://localhost:8080/index.html");

// Initial state
assertEquals("Hello !", page.getElementsByTagName("h1").get(0).asText());

// Set value
((HtmlInput)page.getElementsByTagName("input").get(0)).setValueAttribute("world");

// New state
assertEquals("Hello world!", page.getElementsByTagName("h1").get(0).asText());
```

It's working solution, but not really pleasure solution. I don't know it is problem of HtmlUnit or Angularjs.

Answer (score 1):

The HtmlUnit issue has now been fixed. AngularJS expressions are now evaluated correctly.

https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/bugs/1559/

Comment: What version is this fixed in? I'm using 2.14 and using BrowserVersion.CHROME or FIREFOX_24 results in unevaluated AngularJS expressions, but using BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_8 does appear to evaluate those expressions.

Comment: Looks like this is not yet in a release (2.14 was released in February ). This fix was made in March and is not yet part of a release. I tried to build from the Latest SVN, but it failed: https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/bugs/1596/

Comment: I've tested this again with the latest SVN branch of 2.15 and I am still required to do the old hack mentioned in the answer by @stephanme . I am using AngularJS 1.0.8.

Answer (score 0):

A similar code I have works fine when my single page app uses angularjs 1.0.4; the only thing different I have to do was tell htmlunit to use FIREFOX_17 instead of the default IE8 in htmlunit 2.12 (Similar to the link you provided but FIREFOX_17 instead of FIREFOX_10)

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17);
```

I upgraded to angularjs 1.2 and boom my page shows up with all the angular placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting, fixed in SVN. Please expect HtmlUnit 2.15 very soon.

The test case now works with Chrome simulation, the reason was querySelectorAll() should be defined in document/element.

Please note, it seems others have already identified the root cause, and giving a minimal test case to HtmlUnit team can have it fixed in a very short time.

Thanks again for your feedback.